# Google Maps v3 Directions Display Render HTML

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a method in the Directions Display class to render the HTML provided in the routes' legs' steps? There's directionsDisplay.setDirections that plots the markers and polyline on the map, but I was hoping for something that would give me the HTML all pretty like. Is this in the API and I'm missing it, or does Google expect the developer to iterate the steps themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel.html

Comment: .setPanel() specifically is what I was looking for. Thank you, sir!